# Cross model fetched properties

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

How do I implement cross-model fetched properties in a core data model? Simply put, let's say I have two models -- a CompanyStructure model that describes departmental hierarchy, and a Employee model that describes all employees. How would I set an employee's department as a fetched property?

I found a similar question asked [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/190705-core-data-cross-model-relationships.html). It's a good description of the problem I'm facing:

> When I setup a fetched property for state in my document entity (in
>   Xcode modeller) it needs the destination set – however, the
>   destination popup only shows entities in the current model. What I
>   want (I think) is a predicate something like:
>
> `State.id == $FETCH_SOURCE.state_id`
>
> in order to relate the document entity to the globally defined state
>   entity in the other model.

BTW, I don't know about $FETCH_SOURCE or $FETCH_ANYTHING_ELSE, so I don't really understand the code block in the quoted segment above. I do know that I can't set the entity for an employee's department fetched property because they're in separate models.

EDIT -- Merging the two data models into one is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetched properties are part of the model, so by definition they are not cross-model. If you want to refer to more than one model you have to do it in code. Also, the definition of the connection between the *Employees* and *Departments* can only be done within a model, unless you use your own UIDs and thus bypass the model metaphor.

They way I do similar tasks, I add additional .h and .m files to my classes, like `ClassName+Additions.h` and I declare "properties" as methods that can be called just like properties such as `[smith department]`. In these files, I can `#include` all the necessary classes from the other model and maintain separate managed object contexts.